# Remove CodePipeline Update from CloudFormation stack's deploy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I'm currently using CDK Synth in order to generate templates that I deploy with a sam deploy command.

The idea behind my work is to deploy my stacks from a GitLab runner, without the use of CodePipeline (which is the actual method of deployement).

I manage to deploy my stack as I want using the template located in the cdk.out, after the CDK Synth command. However, the deploy is triggering the CodePipeline because the template contains a "`"Type": AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline`" section, which leads to a "  `* Modify   cdkpipeline   AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline` operation in the sam deploy command of the stack.

I want to remove this operation in the deploy section, so that the CodePipeline is not triggered.
I can't modify the code in himself, because I need to keep both deployment methods alive.
I also can't use the --guided prompts from the sam deploy command because the scripts are executed from a GitLab runner.

Do you have any clue on achieving this, by passing parameters on the deploy (other libraries are fine to me if it works), or by using a tool that deletes the CodePipeline section in the templates ? Maybe something exists aswell to prevent CDK Synth to generate a CodePipeline section ?

I'm open to any proposal.

Thank you already

Comment: Do you have just 1 stack for your app and your pipeline? You might try splitting them into seperate stacks and then doing a cdk synth StackName of your app stack to just synth that one. - you can also specify its out location. IF that still is synthing the pipeline, you can move the pipeline to its own repo. If thats not feasible, are you using Pipelines, and t he SimpleSynth pipe action? Instead of synthing as your trigger, you can have the pipeline do the synth for you of a specific stack

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually have multiple nested stacks behind my main stack. About the Pipeline, i'm basically trying to get rid of CodePipeline for this deployement method. Actually to be more precise, I want to be able to keep the traditional deployment method with CodePipeline, but I also want to implement a second deployment method from a GitLab runner that deploy thoses stacks, without triggering the CodePipeline pipe. I manage to deploy my stacks from the runner with assets from the cdk.out, but the pipe is triggered afterwise and deploy the stacks another time

Comment: If the Pipeline is in another stack, you can just do `cdk deploy MyAppStack` to deploy only the relevant stack(s).